# navigate to C:Drive via php error

Tags: php

I'm trying to navigate to C drive via PHP on my local drive, this one line of code works fine:

```
<a href='<?php echo'file:///C:\Users\Emily\Documents\'?>' TARGET="_blank" >Clcik Me</a>
```

This works fine from my local drive but as soon as this is on my sever it throws an error. I've been trying to strip and replace slashes but to no luck, hope sone one can help me.

Comment: a button appear but when pressed nothing happens

Comment: You create a hyperlink and a button appears?! Oo That sounds curious :X

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using PHP there at all... What you have is no different from `<a href='file:///C:\\Users\\Emily\\Documents\\' TARGET="_blank">`. Is PHP supposed to add the file path dynamically?

Comment: the userID will be added dynamically yes

Comment: Php = server side, c:\... (in this case) = client side... Impossible.

Answer (score 2):

This is because on the server there is no "C:\Users\Emily\Documents".

You need to make sure that the filepath you use is available to you on the server. My recommendation would be to setup your local machine to have the same filepath which exists on your server.

For example lets say you have a folder named Web, in which you keep  the following files and folders:

> index.php
>
> \images (This is another folder)

From your file if you wanted to access a file in the  images folder, from your index.php file you would access it as "images\FileYouWant.jpg"

Your server should have the same setup so you copy index.php and the images folder into the folder on your server, this way they keep the same file paths.

You can find more on file paths [here](http://www.webdiner.com/webadv/begin/paths.htm)

Comment: he's echoing a string trying to link to a clinet-local file... echo'file:///C:\Users\Emily\Documents\' not a server-side file...

Comment: I understand this thanks but what I need to get to a local drive to delete in theory a local profile stored on C drive so that when the user logs in again it re-downloads a fresher profile of the sever.  is this something I can achieve via active directory?

Comment: Ok I think I understand the question a little better now, you might need to use windows variables to accomplish this. Basically you want to access a users file structure to delete something, but it is my understanding that you cannot do this for security reasons. I think there might be workarounds using VB, but it only works in IE and no other browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access local file links from remote servers. if that were still possible (Like it was many years ago), a remote site could get at your local files...

Comment: so if it was a local sever say when I am back in work tomorrow this might work?

Comment: IF that server was windows-based, and IF you were using the page from the server itself, as in you went to http://localhost/scriptname.php and IF the browser didn't have local-access blocked like most IIS boxes usually do by default.

Comment: its a Linux LAMP sever, and as its a school I would think local access would be locked down via user type.

Answer (score 0):

Your server OS maybe not windows and file path is different!

Try to debug with `<?php var_dump(real_path('file_path.php')); ?>`

Comment: its a local windows drive not on the sever